# How to Insert Product Selection Widget into Backend Form?

Tags: product, adminhtml, forms, widgets

Magento has a widget where I can select a product. I need to embed it into my form. To be more clear I will provide screenshot:
[image]

From this widget I need only product id. I can see that I need something like this:

```
<id_path translate="label">
    <visible>1</visible>
    <required>1</required>
    <label>Product</label>
    <type>label</type>
    <helper_block>
        <type>adminhtml/catalog_product_widget_chooser</type>
        <data>
            <button translate="open">
                <open>Select Product...</open>
            </button>
        </data>
    </helper_block>
    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
</id_path>
```

But didn't found yet how to use it. I will be appreciate for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I was looking for:

```
$product1Link = $fieldset->addField('product1_link', 'label', array(
        'name' => 'product1_link',
        'label' => Mage::helper('abc_productbundles')->__('Product 1'),
        'class' => 'widget-option',
        'value' => $model->getProduct1Link(),
        'required' => true,
    ));

$model->unsProduct1Link();
$helperBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/catalog_product_widget_chooser');
if ($helperBlock instanceof Varien_Object) {
    $helperBlock->setConfig($this->getChooserConfig())
        ->setFieldsetId($fieldset->getId())
        ->setTranslationHelper(Mage::helper('abc_productbundles'))
        ->prepareElementHtml($product1Link);
}
```

Comment: `$this->getChooserConfig()` is its your defined method or magento?

Comment: Magento method as I remember

Comment: I'm trying the same but the button appears to be too small and without any label.

Comment: @MohammadFaisal you need to implement the method yourself, and it returns the button text. See the improved answer

Answer (score 4):

I assume that you are creating an own widget - the following does not apply for plain admin forms.

You simply put that snipped in the `<parameters>` section of your widget configuration (`widget.xml').

When the user chooses a product, the parameter `id_path` would be set in your widget.

Inside of your widget block you can get this parameter like this:

```
$this->getData('id_path');
```

The ID path contains stuff like 'product/123' - you probably only want the product id:

```
list($dummy, $productId) = explode("/", $this->getData('id_path'))
```

Comment: list didn'T work as expected - i had to

list(, $productId) = explode("/",$this->getData('id_path'));